# What are the ten courses of action (kamma)?

Tags: theravada, karma, visuddhimagga

In the Visuddhimagga, on the topic of *virtue*, there is a reference to the ten courses of action (kamma):

> Furthermore, virtue as volition is the seven volitions [that accompany
>   the first seven] of **the [ten] courses of action (kamma)** in one who
>   abandons the killing of living things, and so on. Virtue as
>   consciousness-concomitant is the [three remaining] states consisting
>   of non-covetousness, non-ill will, and right view, stated in the way
>   beginning, “Abandoning covetousness, he dwells with a mind free from
>   covetousness” *(D I 71)*.

I know the quote is taken out of context from the chapter, but I was just wondering about the ten courses of action (kamma), and their reference and significance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. What are the ten courses of action & their significance?

They are unwholesome and wholesome behaviors that lead people to live unhappily or happily now & in the future.

**Unwholesome Course**
<sub>*Bodily Conduct*</sub>
1. Killing & harming living beings.
2. Taking what is not given.
3. Sexual misconduct.
<sub>*Verbal Conduct*</sub>
4. Lying.
5. Slandering.
6. Harsh talk.
7. Useless Idle chattering.
<sub>*Mental Conduct*</sub>
8. Covetous thinking.
9. Hateful thinking.
10. Seeing distortedly with wrong view.

**Wholesome Course**
<sub>*Bodily Conduct*</sub>
1. Abandoning killing & harming living beings.
2. Abandoning taking what is not given.
3. Abandoning sexual misconduct.
<sub>*Verbal Conduct*</sub>
4. Abandoning lying.
5. Abandoning slandering.
6. Abandoning harsh talk.
7. Abandoning useless idle chattering.
<sub>*Mental Conduct*</sub>
8. Abandoning covetous thinking.
9. Abandoning hateful thinking.
10. Seeing undistortedly with right view.
<sub>(You can find details about them in the references provided below.)</sub>

### 2. What are their references?

You can find them in many discourses throughout the *[Pāḷi Canon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%81li_Canon)*, specially in the 10th book of the Numerical Discourses (*Aṅguttara Nikāya*).

Two examples are: *[AN 10.176, Cunda (Cunda-suttaṃ)](http://lirs.ru/lib/sutra/The_Numerical_Discourses_of_the_Buddha,Anguttara_Nikaya,Bodhi,2012.pdf#page=1518)* & *[MN 41, Brahmans of Sala (Sāleyyaka-suttaṃ)](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.041.nymo.html)*.

Answer (score 3):

From the textbook Grade 11 Buddhism, Published by the ministry of education of Sri Lanka, they are:

1.Kamma from Mind

> 1. Abhidya - Wish of " May others property become mine"
> 2. Viyapada - Wish of " May other (or I) suffer or die"
> 3. Mithyadrushti - Wrong beliefs ex: there is no effect of kamma

2.Kamma from words

> 1. Lying
> 2. Bitter words
> 3. Columny
> 4. Telling bare words

3.Kamma from deeds

> 1. killing
> 2. Stealing
> 3. Sexual actions other than wife

**To fulfill the Kamma there should be 4 things to complete**

```
1. There should be a victim of it (Self or other)
2. There should have will to commit it
3. Should have made planning to do it
4. Commit it
```

If one of above not is there, Kamma was not been done.